# html5 Video should start from a certain time and loop

Tags: javascript, html, video

I need to Loop the video from 50 to 60 seconds, then on click should loop normally from 0 to the end.

I have a functionality fully working from 0 to 10 seconds but I need it to work from 50 to 60.

Any API help please, I tried `loadedmetadata` but didn't work.

Would be nice to understand what I'm missing in here

Like this works, but Not if I put **50 to 60**

```
  if (this.currentTime >= 10) {
        this.currentTime = 0; // change time index here
      }
```

```js
var video = document.getElementById('videoElm');

 

const playShort = function() {
  if (this.currentTime >= 60) {
    this.currentTime = 50; // change time index here
  }
};
const playFull = function() {
  if (this.currentTime >= 24) {
    this.currentTime = 0; // change time index here
  }
};

function playShortVideo() {
  video.removeEventListener("timeupdate", playFull, false)
  video.addEventListener("timeupdate", playShort, false);
  video.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", playShort, false);


  video.load();
  video.play();
}

function playFullVideo() {
  video.removeEventListener("timeupdate", playShort, false)
  video.addEventListener("timeupdate", playFull, false);
  
  video.load();
  video.play();
}

//play short video by default
playShortVideo();


//CLICK events 
var btnshort = $('.shortvideo');
var btnfull = $('.fullvideo');
btnshort.click(function() {

  playShortVideo();
});

btnfull.click(function() {
  playFullVideo();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <video id="videoElm" autoplay muted controls loop>
    <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" type="video/webm">
</video>

</div>

<button class="shortvideo">play 2 secs only</a><br>

<button class="fullvideo">loop full video</button>
```

Comment: What code did you use for 0 to 10 seconds?

Comment: here you go, I put the code above, I've also have a https://jsfiddle.net/davidesitua/atknexjv/

Comment: Problem is, it doesn’t always reach the “full 60”. Log `this.currentTime` to console in your `timeupdate`, and you’ll see what I mean. If you click around to move the play cursor, then you end up in situations where in one call of this event handler, you have 59-point-something - and then before `timeupdate` fires the next time, the video has already ended. If you need this to work at the very end of the video - then I guess you’ll have to implement handling for _that_ event as well.

Comment: ok, but also on 59 seconds doesn't work. would you be able to help?